# PHP only printing first line of CSV

Tags: php, csv

I am having troubles reading a CSV file. So far, I am able to open the CSV and read the first line.

My CSV file looks like this (notice each new line):

```
SMITH
PHIL
CHARLIE
SALLY
ETC
```

I save the file in excel as a CSV, but it is getting caught up on each line break.

My current code looks like this:

```
<?php 
$file = fopen('surnames.csv', 'r');

$data = fgetcsv($file);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

fclose($file);

?>
```

Current output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => SMITH
)
```

Any help is appreciated. My anticipated output is obviously a single array with all of the values.

Thank  you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to loop over each line to read the whole file, otherwise you're only reading the first line in the file:

```
$data = array();
while( ($line = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
    $data[] = $line;
}
```

Now `$data` will be a multidimensional array with every line from the CSV file.

Answer (score 4):

[`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) only gets one line at a time. Your code should be more along the lines of:

```
<?php 
$file = fopen('surnames.csv', 'r');

echo "<pre>";
while( ($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== false ) {
    print_r($data);
}
echo "</pre>";

fclose($file);
```

Comment: You need a strict comparison in the `while` loop, otherwise values that type-cast to `false` will break the loop, even though the file may not be completely read. Also, this doesn't adhere to the OP's request: My anticipated output is obviously **a single array** with all of the values.

Comment: @nickb True. A blank line in the file will result in a `NULL` return, which will loosely evaluate to `false`. I missed that last line too, have an upvote for your answer then.

Comment: Not a problem, just wanted to point it out. Also, for clarification, I don't believe `NULL` would be returned, an empty string would come back, which also loosely evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @nickb that's what it says in [the doc page](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Comment: Well, the doc page says that `array( null)` would be returned, which does not type-cast to false.

Comment: So, it looks like either way, each line is an individual array as opposed to an array with individual lines. One is a multidimensional @nickb, and one is just a bunch of individual arrays

Comment: @Alpinestar22 if you want the raw lines of text instead of an array, then you should be using [`fgets()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) instead of [`fgetcsv()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).